# \r\n not splitting string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, split, newline, aura-framework

I have a string which is multiline. I update this on SFL case object field.
When i extract the same from database using SOQL, it appends \r\n\r\n whenever multiline text is found. I tried using different regex expressions with split(\r\n) or split(\r\n) and some more as suggested in different articles, but none of them are helping.

split(\r\n) it removes \r\n from my string but replaces it with ,,

What approach should i take.

```
SFL input--> This is line 1
             This is line 2

Output--> This is line 1 \r\n\r\n  This is line 2
when using split output--> This is line 1 ,,This is line 2

expected-->
This is line 1
This is line 2
```

Please help.

Comment: add what you have tried so far.

Comment: var arr = string12.split(/\r?\n/);
        console.log('arr====>'+ arr);
        const result = string12.split(/[\r\n]+/)
        console.log('result===============>'+ result);
Both above codes will remove \r\n\r\n from my code but split(/\r?\n/) appends ,, when encounters new line and split(/[\r\n]+/) appends , when new line is encountered. I am trying to split my lines when \r\n is encountered.

Comment: "_it removes \r\n from my string but replaces it with ,_" No, it doesn't. The comma is added to the stringified format of the array `split` creates. You've to iterate through the array, or join it to a string again to get the actual content of the array. If you just showed your real code, we'll see how you're using the array.

Comment: Can you please help me on that iteration? I tried for iteration using length of my converted string, then used split on , by its ascii. Something like below

for ( i=0; i<= arr.length; i++)
{

a1= arr.charcodeAt(i);
a2= arr.charcodeAt(i+1);

if (a1== 44 && a2== 44)
{
 arr.split(,,);
}
}

Comment: Umm ... Again, there's no commas in the array `split` creates (unless the text itself contains commas). When you put an array to HTML (ex. el.innerHTML or e.textContent = array), the array is implicitly converted to a string, and that conversion contains the commas. Do it like `el.textContent = array.join('');`.

Comment: It looks like you don't need the array at all. Use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) instead of split, something like `output = input.replace(/\r?\n/g, '');`. The question mark is just for a case the new-line characters are not in Windows format.

Comment: output = input.replace(/\r?\n/g, ''); is breaking the code. It does not print anything.

Comment: Show your code, [that expression works as it is](https://jsfiddle.net/sLe8zu4b/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a character set in the regular expression separator.

```js
const string = 'This is line 1\r\n\r\nThis is line 2'
const result = string.split(/[\r\n]+/)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
My input is: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem

Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an which is in 2 lines.
Output based on your suggestion: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem ,Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
It is adding a , but I want string to be split into two lines whenever new line is encountered. Can  you please help

Comment: You could use [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) on the result, passing an empty string as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to split by '\n`and then`.trim()` each string?

Or you can try this:

```js
var str = `hello
world

ok`;
var arr = str.split(/\r?\n/)
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. Here is my input and output. I am expecting to have my output same as input view.
Input:  Additional CommentsLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem

Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
Output: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem ,,Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
Expected: When new line is encountered, it should split my string and print in next line.